# Emacs24使用中に不意にWindowsの言語設定がENGに変化してしまう症状の対策はありますか？

Tags: windows, emacs

Windows向けにビルドされたEmacsを使っていると、タイプ中に何の前触れもなく突然Windowsの言語設定がENGに変化しまい、キーボードの記号配列が突然変わってキーボードのキートップ表示どおりに入力できなくなってしまうことがあるのですが、何かの設定で防止できるでしょうか。

現状は「またか・・・」と思いつつ、マウスでタスクバーのENGをクリックして日本語(Microsoft IMEかGoogle日本語入力かのいずれか)に戻しています。

OSはWindowsXP, 7, 10と変えてきていますがどれでも発生しており、32ビット版OSでも64ビット版OSでも発生しています。また、特定のキー入力で再現するわけでもなく、不定期に発生します。

Emacsの方は、http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/GNU/emacs/windows/ で配布されているEmacs24系最新バージョンを使っています。

またPCのハード依存ということでもなく、HPやDELLのデスクトップPC、PanasonicのノートPCで発生しました。

一度、Windowsの言語設定でENGを削除して日本語だけにしてみたことがありますが、同現象が再発して、言語設定を確認するとENGがいつの間にか蘇っていました。

Comment: [gunupack版Emacs](https://ja.osdn.net/projects/gnupack/)で（たぶん）同じ現象になっていましたが、「言語設定でENGを削除」して以来起こらなくなった記憶があります。記憶が曖昧なのとgunupack版Emacsには所謂IMEパッチが当てられているので、事情が異なるかもしれませんが。

Answer (score 9):

左Alt + Shift 「入力言語を切り替える」を押しているのではないでしょうか。このキーバインディングはEmacsではなくWindowsが処理しています。「テキストサービスと入力言語」ダイアログでキーシーケンスを割り当てなしにしてみてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

Windows のバグで
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
「入力言語の切り替え」を設定していないのにショートカットが有効になるというものがあります。
一度、有効にした後、無効にすることで、ショートカットを完全に無効にすることができます。